Movable Windows in React
I would like to implement a movable and minimizable chat window in react. So that the user can pop it up and drag it wherever it is needed. For that I need something like a popup or window that can be dragged around, but I haven't found anything actually compatible with react 18 (this includes all in one chat window solutions). Is there something like this? Like a popup that can be dragged around the screen (and ideally remembers where it was)?
